# Strings/words manipulations using std::string::compare (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, loops

#### Problem

I am first dividing a string into different words and then checking *if reverse of a word is present or not*. I am making a different string for each word and then reversing it and them comparing it with other strings.

#### Code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
string str;
getline(cin,str);

cout<<"the string inputted is "<<str;

char ch=str[0];
int i=0;
int sp_count=0;
while(ch!='\0')
{
    ch=str[i];
    if(ch==' ')
    {
        sp_count++;
    }   
    i++;
}

string words[sp_count+1];
ch=str[0];
i=0;
int w=0,it=0;
while(ch!='\0')
{
    ch=str[i];
    if(ch==' ')
    {
        w++;
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    words[w]=words[w]+ch;
    i++;
}
for(int i=0;i<sp_count+1;i++)
{   
cout<<words[i]<<endl;
}       
for(int i=0;i<sp_count+1;i++)
{   string temp=words[i];
    reverse(temp.begin(),temp.end());
    for(int j=i+1;j<sp_count+1;j++)
    {   int x=10;
        x=temp.compare(words[j]);
        if(x==0)
        {
            cout<<"strings "<<temp << " and "<<words[j]<<" are equal"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"strings "<<temp << " and "<<words[j]<<" are not equal"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

When I input the string:

```
Hello is si
```

Output is:

```
strings olleh and is are not equal
strings olleh and si are not equal
strings si and si are not equal
```

The code does not return correct output.

Comment: This works as expected: https://ideone.com/9mqB5e  Since your question does not contain a [mcve] I can't test your code, I can only tell you there must be something wrong with it. Perhaps you should use a debugger or print more data.

Comment: Also, your complexity is O(N^2) which is very poor. Consider using a different data-structure (if you have more than 10 elements). Maybe use `std::set<std::string>` (totals O(N log N) with a good constant, `std::unordered_set<std::string>` (totals O(N) with a very poor constant), or even a binary search in a sorted list of strings (totals O(N log N) with a very good constant)

Comment: Can you please give complete code. When I set `words = {"hello", "is", "si"}` and `sp_count = words.size() - 1` then everything works as expected.

Comment: In the loop where you print the words, change `cout<<words[i]<<endl;` to `cout << "'" << words[i] << "'" << endl;` and you will see the problem. It should also be quite obvious in the output where you print that the strings are not equal. Consider searching for a better way to split strings, or how to accept input word by word.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, Retired Ninja is correct, you have an issue in the way you slice out the induvial words, particularly the last word. It has a trailing white space, and so of course "si " and "si" are not equal.

Try the following change in the while block:

```
while ((ch = str[i]) != '\0') {
    // ch = str[i];
    if (ch == ' ') {
        w++;
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    words[w] = words[w] + ch;
    i++;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
strings olleh and is are not equal
strings olleh and si are not equal
strings si and si are equal
```

You were incrementing `i`, not updating `ch`, but comparing the old `ch` value against `0`.